# Converting columns into rows without specifying the column names

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
bad_df <- data.frame(
id = c("id001", "id002", "id003"),
participant.1 = c("Jana", "Marina", "Vasilei"),
participant.2 = c("Niko", "Micha", "Niko"),
role.1 = c("writer", "writer", "speaker"),
role.2 = c("observer", "observer", "observer"),
stringsAsFactors = F
)
bad_df
```

I would need to gather it into something like this. Each row should contain one id, participant and role.

```
good_df <- data.frame(
id = c("id001", "id001", "id002", "id002", "id003", "id003"),
participant = c("Jana", "Niko", "Marina", "Micha", "Vasilei", "Niko"),
role = c("writer", "observer", "writer", "observer", "speaker", "observer"),
stringsAsFactors = F
)
good_df
```

I see there are countless questions very much like this, but I find it very difficult to understand how to apply `tidyr` or `reshape2` into this situation. I understand this must be somehow possible with gather().

However, the data frame could contain larger number of participants and corresponding roles, so ideally the method would not demand specifying the column names. One solution which I came up with is below, but I don't think it is the most elegant way to go. And I still would need to deal with some data frames containing participant.3, role.3 etc.

```
good_df2 <- rbind(bad_df %>% select(id, participant.1, role.1) %>% 
                    rename(participant = participant.1, role = role.1),
                 bad_df %>% select(id, participant.2, role.2) %>% 
                    rename(participant = participant.2, role = role.2))
good_df2
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the devel version of `data.table` ie. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(bad_df), measure=list(grep('participant', names(bad_df)),
    grep('role', names(bad_df))))[order(id)][, variable:= NULL]
#      id  value1   value2
#1: id001    Jana   writer
#2: id001    Niko observer
#3: id002  Marina   writer
#4: id002   Micha observer
#5: id003 Vasilei  speaker
#6: id003    Niko observer
```

Or we can use `merged.stack` where we need to only provide the prefix of the unique columns.  Based on the prefix values, it will group the columns that have the same prefix together.

```
library(splitstackshape)
merged.stack(bad_df, var.stubs=c('participant', 'role'), 
                       sep='var.stubs')[, 2:= NULL]
#      id participant     role
#1: id001        Jana   writer
#2: id001        Niko observer
#3: id002      Marina   writer
#4: id002       Micha observer
#5: id003     Vasilei  speaker
#6: id003        Niko observer
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(bad_df, Var, Val, -id) %>% 
        separate(Var, into=c('Var1', 'Var2')) %>% 
        spread(Var1, Val) %>%
        select(-Var2)
#    id participant     role
#1 id001        Jana   writer
#2 id001        Niko observer
#3 id002      Marina   writer
#4 id002       Micha observer
#5 id003     Vasilei  speaker
#6 id003        Niko observer
```

Comment: @Frank I am  not sure how to interpret that sentence.  But, we need to atleast specify the columns measure columns.  In `merged.stack` that can be done.

Comment: I mean that you are writing "participant.1" "participant.2" ... and doing so seems to violate the premise of the OP, which is about avoiding enumerating the columns (as the splitstackshape solution does) because the number of participants isn't known ahead of time (or something like that).

Answer (score 3):

I'd go this way in `base` R:

```
 #find the participant columns
 partCol<-grep("part",colnames(bad_df))
 #... and the role columns
 roleCol<-grep("role",colnames(bad_df))
 data.frame(id=rep(bad_df$id,each=length(partCol)),
            partecipant=as.vector(as.matrix(t(bad_df[,partCol]))),
            role=as.vector(as.matrix(t(bad_df[,roleCol]))))
```